# SQL Injection in Stored Procedure Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, xss, sql-injection

I have a stored procedure which is going to return search results depending on what the user has typed into a standard search text box. Upon pressing enter in the search box I'm passing  the query to search.aspx?q=whatever user entered.

search.aspx has a sqldatasource which accepts a querystring paramater and calls a stored procedure which joins a number of tables and contains the following where clauses...

```
where (description like '%' + @query + '%' or title like '%' + @query + '%'  or     calls.call_id like @query or r.firstname = @query or r.lastname = @query
or n.note like '%' + @query + '%')
```

...is this sql injection safe i.e.using paramaters like this?

Thanks,

Comment: No, it is NOT, it if far away from safe.

Comment: Good job I asked then! recommend anything?

Comment: @ljh would you care to elaborate?  The query is sanitizing input by using parameters.  It looks safe to me.

Comment: Unless you make a string and EXEC the string, it looks safe to me.

Comment: yeah I could try that @didirec...

Comment: good points on what not to do in your sp http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-injection-are-parameterized-queries.html

Comment: If user input is just a %, what you will return, it possibly return all the data, is that acceptable?

Comment: You're right @ljh - i'll fix that. cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not susceptible to SQL injection because it uses SQL parameters.  Let's say someone tried to perform [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) by providing as a value for `@query`:

`'; DROP TABLE STUDENTS;`

You're still safe with the code you provided because the query is all yours with the exception of the parameter which isn't SQL; it's a string.  Even if the string contains SQL, it isn't ever executed unless your stored procedure actually [executed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) it.  Never ever ever do that (unless you have a really good reason to (but even then, you should probably redesign first)).  SQL injection can be easy to avoid just by using parameters to sanitize user input.

Comment: ahhh, correct, it would need to be dynamic sql (ie. `exec (@query)`)

Comment: even if you were to use dynamic SQL within SP then execute sql string using "sp_executesql" and pass the parameters to it.